# How to assign a hex literal to a `bytes` variable in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I am trying to put 0x11 into bytes, but I keep getting an error.

As I know, the bytes type supports the flexible size up to 32 bytes.
However, I do not know what I can't even set 1 byte there.

```solidity
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract practice {
    bytes1 public a = 0x11;
    bytes  public c = 0x11; // an error occured, why is it??
    bytes public b = '0x11'; // It is not even 0x11, why do I have to put string value into bytes...? 
}
```

Please let me know this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x11` is an integer constant. This type is not implicitly convertible to `bytes` and there's no explicit conversion but you can use `bytes.concat()` function for that:

```solidity
bytes public c = bytes.concat(0x11);
```

In this case, however what you really want is a [hexadecimal literal](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#hexadecimal-literals):

```
bytes public c = hex"11";
```

> bytes public b = '0x11'; // It is not even 0x11, why do I have to put string value into bytes...?

This does not put the number `0x11` in your variable. It puts `0x30783131` in it instead - i.e. the hexadecimal values of the ASCII characters in your string. It's wrong.